# SNMP mib parser

Tags: c#, snmp, sharp-snmp

How can I convert SNMP-OID to string, by the mib-file?

I use SNMPSharpLib, but I don't know how to parse the objects.

I recieve traps (v2), and they contain "ObjectIDentifier" filed, but I need to translate they to English-text.

Answer (score 1):

You should review snmptranslate sample,

https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib/blob/55a03bf575f0b5a518dab10b595dd09b2a1798ae/archived/snmptranslate_cs/Program.cs

It demonstrates what is required to perform the translation.

**Update**

Due to the introduction of #SNMP Pro edition, MIB document related features are removed from #SNMP Library.