# How to parse the snmp trap handled using sharpsnmplib

Tags: snmp, snmp-trap, sharp-snmp

Using the translate sample mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/a/12278067/10955742 we are unable to parse the trap messages. The sample talks more about loading the modules and parsing the object tree. Now what are these module files are these MIB files?

I would like to parse the trap received. Am using the sharpsnmplib for setting my snmp manager and the snmptrapd

Comment: Welcome! Are you getting an error message? Do you have a code sample?

Comment: Thank! for the comment. Okay here is what I am trying to. I have an SNMP Agent(device) which sends traps (alarms etc..) to handle the trap messages am using the snmptrapd provided by sharpsnmplib. These trap messages received has details of sender (ipaddress), OID and the message which is an integer value. So in this case if I have to parse the received message and extract OID and identify to which parameter (in the MIB) this message is. I was referring [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/q/12277028/10955742) post for parsing the trap messages.

Comment: And what will be the input to "ReloadableObjectRegistry", modules? are these mib files? Am referring to the translate sample shared https://stackoverflow.com/a/12278067/10955742                                                   IObjectRegistry registry = new ReloadableObjectRegistry("modules");

Comment: You'll need to present your [MCVE] and clearly describe the problem.

Comment: MIB document processing has been moved to the commercial library, https://pro.sharpsnmp.com/getting-started/assembly-features.html #SNMP Library no longer has that feature.